# Spring Integration - Is conditional wire-tapping possible?

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to do a "conditional" `wire-tapping` ? If yes, can someone throw some light on it ?

Below is my use case:

I've a property (key-value pair) configured in my LDAP server. This property holds a boolean value.
Also I'm `wire-tapping` various direct channels in my configuration for some logging purpose. The channel to which the `wire-tap` does a hands-off is an executor channel; this is to achieve async logging.

Now, my use case is I should having this wire-tap "enabled" only if the boolean property defined in my LDAP server is true. Else the `wire-tap` should not happen.

I thought of achieving it through a router but couldn't exactly figure out how to do it because a `wire-tap` doesn't have any `input-channel`.

Many thanks in advance !

Best Regards
LB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of a wiretap, make `input` a `publish-subscribe-channel` with the first subscriber (`order="1"`) being the filter; then add the executor channel after the filter?

The second subscriber would be your main flow (`order="2"`).

Or; subclass `WireTap` and override `preSend` putting your filter logic there; if it passes, invoke `super.preSend()`.

Add the custom wiretap as a bean to the interceptors (instead of `wire-tap`).

**EDIT:**

Well, it turns out the wire tap already has this capability...

```
<channel id="accepting">
    <interceptors>
        <wire-tap channel="wireTapChannel" selector="mySelector"/>
    </interceptors>
</channel>
```

...where `mySelector` is a `MessageSelector` bean - you simply implement the `accept` method and only messages that cause the selector to return `true` are tapped. So you can do your LDAP lookup there; possibly cached for a short period to avoid too much overhead.

Sometimes even we forget some of the capabilities of this amazing framework :)

Comment: For the first approach, I may end up changing lot many of my direct channels to pub-sub because my wire-tap intercepts lot many of these direct channels using "pattern". Moreover, my wire-tap is not on a single channel. The second approach looks somewhat feasible to me. Just one quick clarification - how do I add a custom wiretap as a bean to the interceptors ? Also from this use case, do you think a "new feature" can be put up in future SI release for an attribute on <wire-tap> that will make it enabled/disabled in runtime ?

Comment: Edited - the `wire-tap` already has this capability. For future reference, you can simply use a `<bean/>` child element on the `<interceptors/>` to configure a custom interceptor.

Comment: You guys are wizard ! The "selector" approach works like a charm..Tx Gary and Artem ! :)

Comment: It seems you are new to Stack Overflow. It is customary to `accept` the answer if it solves your issue, to help other users with similar questions.

Comment: I'm aware of it and tried to click the "big" check mark against your answer (multiple times) but nothing happens..it doesn't turn up green !   **EDIT** - Just tried again and it worked this time..accepted your answer..Many tx again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `wire-tap` is some patter which just starts a new message flow, which begins from that `<wire-tap>`'s `channel`.

Since you say that you want to "suffocate" the `wire-tap` flow by some condition, there is just enough to place `<filter>` in the beginning of that flow. Something like this:

```
<int:channel id="input">
   <int:interceptors>
       <int:wire-tap channel="logging"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="logging">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:filter input-channel="logging" output-channel="loggingProcess"
    ref="ldapService" method="checkState"/>
```

Is it OK for you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for replying Artem. I do agree with the above approach and it does address my query to an extent...the only catch is..it will create a new task for the executor. I want my check to be part of caller thread itself. In other words, the channel "input" should be wire-tapped only if condition is met, else not. Any possibility for that ?

Comment: Move the executor to `loggingProcess` (or see my alternative answer).